# How to set up stanford CRF classifier to listen http requests?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a custom CRF classifier and I use it listen to socket requests:

```
java -mx2g -cp stanford-ner-2018-10-16\stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -loadClassifier model\custom-ner.gz -port 9191 -outputFormat inlineXML
```

How to listen to http requests instead?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
java -mx4g -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05\*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9191 -outputFormat inlineXML  -serverProperties server.properties
```

Where `server.properties` contains:

```
annotators=ner
ner.model=model/custom-ner.gz
outputFormat=xml
```

But I'm having two major issues:

1. I can't find the option to output in the inlineXML format.
2. This is so slow compared to the socket way (it seems to be loading many libraries which I'm not sure I need)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you run the full pipeline it is running then full suite of `ner` tools, including a dictionary based system for fine-grained `ner`.  You should set `-ner.applyFineGrained false` if you don't want to use those.

The full write up on the `ner` system is here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

At this time the server doesn't have an `inlineXML` option, as it is returning a full set of annotations, so this output type would not make sense.  I suppose we could make a subclass of AnnotationOutputter that handles this case.